# local database synchronized with the remote webservice database

Tags: android

I am working in the application where the data is stored directly to the local storage and when the user save the data, it will save in the local database first then if the internet connection is provided then the local database is synchronized with the web service database.

Answer (score 1):

You can build json "dialog" between your client app and webservice just using http post requests.